# Issues with Javamail with Gmail: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap, gmail-imap

So I'm automating gmail using JavaMail for Office Framework. When I tried it in my personal project it worked. But it doesn't work when used in Framework.

My noob code looks like this:

```
     public class EmailUtils {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session;
        Folder inbox;
        Store store;
        private String imapProtocol = "imap";
        private String imapHost = "imap.gmail.com";

        private void connect(String email, String appPassword) throws MessagingException {
            try {
             setProperties_IMAP();
             session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                     store = session.getStore(imapProtocol);
             store.connect(imapHost, email, appPassword);
             session.setDebug(true);
             inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
             inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Reporter.fail("Email Utility Initilisation Failed");
             GenericMethods.printStacktrace(e);
            }
        }

        private void setProperties_IMAP() {
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.store.protocol","imap");
            props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.1");
        }

        public void search(String email, String appPassword) {
            try {
             connect(email, appPassword);
             SearchTerm sender = newFromTerm(new InternetAddress("example@gmail.com"));

             Message[] messages = inbox.search(sender);
             for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                  Message message = messages[i];
                  System.out.println("-----------------------");
                  getTextFromMessage(message);
                  some_code();
                  System.out.println("-----------------------");
              }
              System.out.println("no more messages");
              store.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              GenericMethods.printStacktrace(e);
          }
      }
```

Error I get is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V
> at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.initStreams(Protocol.java:148)
> at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:127)
> at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:126)
> at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:756)
> at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:691)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
> at utils.EmailUtils.connect(EmailUtils.java:45)
> at utils.EmailUtils.search(EmailUtils.java:78)
> at pageObjects.pages.EmailContentVerificationPage.verifyEmailContent(EmailContentVerificationPage.java:129)
> at shoppe.tests.EmailContentVerification.emailVerification(EmailContentVerification.java:18)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

When I used the code in Framework I got: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate

I was able to resolve it By modifying java.security file, thanks to stack overflow. but immediately after that I got above said error.

My environment is:

JDK 1.8, Windows 10 pro

Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Pls Help. Also Code critics are most welcome

Comment: These errors are mostly related to jar versions being old or mismatched. Try with newer version of `mail` and `jsoup` and see what you get.

Comment: @hell_storm2004 thanks for reply. I've tried with latest dependencies, but no luck